# biblatex ignores own lbx file

Tags: biblatex, languages

I’m trying to build an own `biblatex` style named `musuos` for that I created the two style files `musuos.bbx` and `musuos.cbx` which look like the following:

```
\ProvidesFile{authoryear-musuos.bbx}[2011/05/06 v1.0 Musikwissenschaften Uni Osnabrueck]
\RequireBibliographyStyle{authortitle}
...
\endinput
```

and

```
\ProvidesFile{authoryear-musuos.cbx}[2011/05/06 v1.0 Musikwissenschaften Uni Osnabrueck]
\RequireCitationStyle{verbose-ibid}
\ExecuteBibliographyOptions{
    autocite=footnote, 
    labelyear=true,
    dashed=false,
    urldate=long,
}
...
\endinput
```

If I load them with `\usepackage[style=musuos]{biblatex}` everything is fine. But now I need to adjust a language string. For that I built the file `german-musuos.lbx` and saved it in the same directory as the style files.

```
\ProvidesFile{german-musuos.lbx}[2011/09/10 v1.0  biblatex localization file]

\InheritBibliographyExtras{german}

\NewBibliographyString{bibcitedas}

\DefineBibliographyStrings{%
  bibcitedas = {{zitiert als}{zit. als}},
  urlseen = {am},
}

\endinput
```

But it seems that the `lbx` file isn’t loaded. What do I have to do to make `biblatex` use it?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Skimming the files of [`biblatex-dw`](http://ctan.org/pkg/biblatex-dw), it seems you have to include the following code line in `authoryear-musuos.bbx`:

```
\DeclareLanguageMapping{german}{german-musuos}
```

BTW, the `authoryear` prefix seems to be improper for a style that combines features of `authortitle` and `verbose`.

Comment: Thank’s, that works :-) the authoryear prefixes came form testing something, I deleted them.