# Using own .lbx file with biblatex

Tags: biblatex

To whom it may concern:

I'm trying to use a .lbx file as an own language support for the bibliographical references. The file is already located in C:\texlive\2019\texmf-dist\tex\latex\biblatex\lbx, and named 'basque.lbx'. Currently, the babel package supports the basque language.

I have created the following MWE:

```latex
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage[basque]{babel}
\usepackage[sorting=none, style=numeric-comp]{biblatex}{biblatex}
\addbibresource{bibliografia.bib}
  
\begin{document}

\cite{1868VonHelmholtz,1871Thomson,1883Reynolds,1894Reynolds,1922Richardson,1931Tollmien}

{
\let \clearpage \relax
\printbibheading
\printbibliography[heading=subbibliography, type=book, title={Liburu zein monografiak}]
\printbibliography[heading=subbibliography, type=article, title={Aldizkari artikuluak}]
\printbibliography[heading=subbibliography, type=report, title={Txosten teknikoak}]
}

\end{document}
```

with the "bibliografia.bib" file being:

```latex
@article{1868VonHelmholtz,
author = {von Helmholtz, H.},
journal = {Philosophical Magazine},
number = {244},
pages = {337--346},
title = {{On Discontinuous Movements of Fluids}},
volume = {36},
year = {1868}
}

@article{1871Thomson,
author = {Thomson, William},
journal = {Philosophical Magazine},
pages = {362--377},
title = {{Hydrokinetic Solutions and Observations}},
volume = {42},
year = {1871}
}

@article{1883Reynolds,
author = {Reynolds, Osborne F. R. S.},
journal = {Royal Society of London},
pages = {84--99},
title = {{An experimental investigation of the circumstances which determine whether the motion of water shall be direct or sinuous, and of the law of resistance in parallel channels}},
volume = {35},
year = {1883}
}

@article{1894Reynolds,
author = {Reynolds, Osborne},
journal = {Proceedings of the Royal Society of London},
number = {336-339},
pages = {123--164},
title = {{On the dynamical theory of incompressible viscous fluid and the determination of the criterion}},
volume = {56},
year = {1894}
}

@book{1922Richardson,
author = {Richardson, Lewis Fry and Lynch, Peter},
edition = {1},
publisher = {Cambridge University Press},
title = {{Weather Prediction by Numerical Process}},
year = {1922}
}

@techreport{1931Tollmien,
address = {Washington},
author = {Tollmien, W.},
booktitle = {Technical Memorandum, 609},
institution = {National Advisory Committe for Aeronautics (NACA)},
pages = {1--35},
title = {{The Production of Turbulence}},
year = {1931}
}
```

However, the compiling process does not seem to find the 'basque.lbx' file alluded to earlier. In fact, the log file provides the following messages:

```
Package biblatex Info: Trying to load language 'basque'...
Package biblatex Info: ... file 'basque.lbx' not found.


Package biblatex Warning: Language 'basque' not supported.
(biblatex)                Using fallback language 'english' on input line 7.
```

and loads the english language file instead. Any ideas on how to tackle this issue? I have already tried the solution posted in the following thread: [biblatex ignores own lbx file](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/28014/biblatex-ignores-own-lbx-file). But the case is slightly different, and a `\DeclareLanguageMapping` command does not solve the problem.

Comment: don't add local files to texmf-dist, use e.g. texmflocal or your texmfhome.

Comment: Thank you for the fast response. I see there is a texmf-local directory at C:\texlive, but neither placing the file there nor in the C:\textlive\textmf-local\tex\latex\local path solves the problem. Am I missing something else?

Comment: if should go into the right subfolder so texmf-local/tex/latex. Perhaps you need to run `mktexlsr` (normally unneeded for texmf-local, but it doesn't harm to try). Check also if the file name is really correct (windows sometimes add a hidden extension).

Comment: It doesn't seem to work. Windows leaves the file extension unaltered, and I have located it at texmf-local\tex\latex. The error message persists, even after having run ```mktexlsr```. Any other suggestion as to where am I making a mistake?

Comment: does it work if you copy the lbx in the folder of your document?

Comment: Yes, that works! Any idea on how can be made part of the texmf-local tree? Or should I assume that putting the lbx file in the document folder is an accepted good-practice?

Comment: no it should also work in a texmf-tree, I only wanted to be sure that the file itself is fine. But sorry I can't tell you what is wrong on your system. Perhaps you did put it in the wrong place (do you perhaps two tex systems?), or you didn't correctly updated the file name database.

Comment: Ok, you were right. I am using the MikTeX system, not the TeXLive one. The solution is to create a personal directory ```~\mytexmf``` and building a TDS-compliant tree within. It suffices, as you pointed out, to include the ```tex\latex``` directories and to place the lbx file there. Finally, it is necessary to add the path of the newly created ```~\mytextmf``` directory to the list of the root MikTeX directories, which is done via the MikTeX console (Settings -> Directories).
If you wish to post your solution so I can upvote it, please feel free to do so.