# biblatex own .lbx file not found

Tags: biblatex

Using

```
\usepackage[canadian]{babel}
\usepackage[style=canadian]{csquotes}
\usepackage[style=apa]{biblatex}
```

alerted me that `canadian-apa.lbx` does not exist with the error message:

> Package biblatex Warning: File 'canadian-apa.lbx' not found! Ignoring mapping 'canadian' -> 'canadian-apa'.

I went to `C:\texlive\2021\texmf-dist\tex\latex\biblatex-apa`, made a duplicate of `british-apa.lbx`, renamed it `canadian-apa.lbx`, and updated the file to say `\ProvidesFile{canadian-apa.lbx}`. However, the issue persisted.

I found [Using own .lbx file with biblatex](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/569814/using-own-lbx-file-with-biblatex) that mentions we should not put files in `texmf-dist` but rather `texmf-local`, so I tried to put `canadian-apa.lbx` in

- `C:\texlive\texmf-local\tex\latex`
- `C:\texlive\texmf-local\tex\latex\local`
- `C:\texlive\texmf-local\tex\latex\local\biblatex-apa` (created `biblatex-apa` subdirectory)

but all three file locations did not help.

Placing `canadian-apa.lbx` in the folder with the `.tex` file worked, but I'd like to know where I should place the `.lbx` file such that I don't have to keep copying it to project folders.

I am on Windows with TeX Live 2021.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out—I had to run `texhash` after adding the file to `texmf-local/tex/latex/biblatex-apa`.