# biblatex error: langbasque undefined

Tags: biblatex, babel

In a book-length document using `memoir`, `babel`, and `biblatex`, I am getting an error regarding basque even though ***I am not (explicitly) using that language***.

This is happening even after I used the Mac TeXLive Utility to reinstall `biblatex`.

The error, from the log (this listing below is updated after the TeXLive Utility reinstalled `biblatex`):

```
Package biblatex Info: Trying to load language 'english' -> 'mylanguagestrings'
...
Package biblatex Info: ... file 'mylanguagestrings.lbx' found.

(/Users/murray/Library/texmf/tex/latex/biblatex/lbx/mylanguagestrings.lbx
File: mylanguagestrings.lbx 
Package biblatex Info: Trying to load language 'english'...
Package biblatex Info: ... file 'english.lbx' found.

(/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/biblatex/lbx/english.lbx
File: english.lbx 2020/08/23 v3.15a biblatex localization (PK/MW)
)
Package biblatex Info: Trying to load language 'english'...
Package biblatex Info: ... file 'english.lbx' found.

(/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/biblatex/lbx/english.lbx
File: english.lbx 2020/08/23 v3.15a biblatex localization (PK/MW)


/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/biblatex/lbx/english.lbx:571: Pack
age xkeyval Error: `langbasque' undefined in families `blx@lbx'.
```

***What might be causing this error?***

This is new behavior with this document: when I last processed it, two to three months ago, no such error occurred. So the error may be due to some change in `biblatex`.

*I've been unable to reproduce the error in a MWE,* unfortunately. Here, though, is relevant information.

The preamble includes:

```
\usepackage[T2A,T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{amsthm}

\usepackage[russian,french,ngerman,polish,english]{babel}
  \babeltags{russian=russian,french=french,german=ngerman,polish=polish}

\RequirePackage[
  backend=biber,
  bibstyle=mybooknumeric,
  citestyle=numeric,
  dashed=true,
  defernumbers=true,
  urldate=iso,date=iso,seconds=true]%
{biblatex} 

\addbibresource{myyref.bib}
```

The source directory uses the following `biblatex.cfg`:

```
\ProvidesFile{biblatex.cfg}

\DeclareNameAlias{sortname}{family-given}
% Punctuation & delimiter mods:
\DeclareLanguageMapping{english}{mylanguagestrings} % external file!
\renewcommand*{\newunitpunct}{\addcomma\space}
\renewcommand{\subtitlepunct}{\addcolon\addspace}
\renewbibmacro{in:}{%
  \ifentrytype{article}{}{\printtext{\bibstring{in}\intitlepunct}}}

% Field mods:
%\renewcommand*{\bibnamedash}{\rule{3em}{0.4pt}\hspace*{.16667em}\addcomma\addspace}
\renewcommand*{\bibnamedash}{\rule{3em}{0.4pt}\hskip 0.16667em plus 0.01em minus 0.01em\relax \addcomma\addspace}
%
\renewbibmacro*{addendum+pubstate}{%
  \setunit{\addsemicolon\space}%
  \printfield{addendum}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \printfield{pubstate}}
%
\DeclareFieldFormat
  [article,inbook,incollection,inproceedings,patent,thesis,unpublished]
  {title}{\mkbibemph{#1}}% no quote marks
  \DeclareFieldFormat{journaltitle}{#1}
%
\DeclareFieldFormat
  [article,inbook,incollection,inproceedings,patent,thesis,unpublished]
  {volume}{\mkbibbold{#1}}  
\DeclareFieldFormat{pages}{#1}% no prefix for the `pages` field in the bibliography
%  
\DeclareFieldFormat{pages}{#1}% no prefix for the `pages` field

% URL mods:
%
% Original definitions in biblatex.def
% \DeclareFieldFormat{url}{\mkbibacro{URL}\addcolon\space\url{#1}}
\DeclareFieldFormat{url}{\url{#1}}
% \DeclareFieldFormat{urldate}{\mkbibparens{\bibstring{urlseen}\space#1}}
\DeclareFieldFormat{urldate}{\mkbibbrackets{\bibstring{urlseen}\space#1}}

% Book mods:
\renewbibmacro*{publisher+location+date}{%
  \printlist{publisher}%
  \setunit*{\addcomma\space}%
  \printlist{location}%
  \setunit*{\addcomma\space}%
  \usebibmacro{date}%
  \newunit}
  
% Article mods: 
\DeclareFieldFormat[article,periodical]{number}{\bibstring{number}~#1}% number of a journal
%
\renewbibmacro*{journal+issuetitle}{%
  \usebibmacro{journal}%
  \setunit*{\addspace}%
  \iffieldundef{series}
    {}
    {\newunit
     \printfield{series}%
     \setunit{\addspace}}%
  \printfield{volume}%
  \setunit{\addspace}%
  \usebibmacro{issue+date}%
  \setunit{\addcomma\space}%
  \printfield{number}%
  \setunit{\addcolon\space}%
  \usebibmacro{issue}%
  \setunit{\addcomma\space}%
  \printfield{eid}
  \newunit}
```

**Is there something in `biblatex.cfg` that is causing `biblatex` to revert to version 3.15?**

The file `mylanguagestrings` referenced in `biblatex.cfg` is in `~/Library/texmf/tex/latex/biblatex/lbx` and has content:

```
    \ProvidesFile{mylanguagestrings.lbx}
    % with custom-english-ordinal-sscript
    %
    % If don't use babel, then use ``english'' versions of 
    % \InheritBibliographyExtras and \DefineBibliographyStrings
    % Redefines '\mkbibordinal' command so as to elide ordinal suffixes
    %
    \InheritBibliographyExtras{english}
    \DeclareBibliographyExtras{%
      \protected\def\mkbibordinal#1{%
    \begingroup%
     \@tempcnta0#1\relax\number\@tempcnta%%
        \endgroup}%
      \protected\def\mkbibmascord{\mkbibordinal}%
      \protected\def\mkbibfemord{\mkbibordinal}%
    }
    %
    % Original definition in english.lbx:
    % urlseen =    {{visited on}{visited on}},
    \DeclareBibliographyStrings{%
      inherit = {english},
      urlseen = {{accessed}{accessed}},
    }
    \DeclareBibliographyStrings{%
      inherit = {american},
      urlseen = {{accessed}{accessed}},
    }
    \endinput
```

**Is there something in `mylanguagestrings.lbx` that is causing `biblatex` to revert to version 3.15?**

(Just in case it's relevant.) I am also using the following file in `~/Library/texmf/tex/latex/biblatex/bbx`:

```
\ProvidesFile{mybooknumeric.bbx}
\RequireBibliographyStyle{standard}
\RequireBibliographyStyle{numeric}
%
\DeclareBibliographyOption[boolean]{dashed}[true]{%
  \ifstrequal{#1}{true}
    {\ExecuteBibliographyOptions{pagetracker}%
     \renewbibmacro*{bbx:savehash}{\savefield{fullhash}{\bbx@lasthash}}}
    {\renewbibmacro*{bbx:savehash}{}}}
%
\newbibmacro*{bbx:savehash}{%
  \savefield{fullhash}{\bbx@lasthash}}
   
\renewbibmacro*{author}{%
  \ifboolexpr{
    test \ifuseauthor
    and
    not test {\ifnameundef{author}}
  }
  {\usebibmacro{bbx:dashcheck}
    {\bibnamedash}
    {\printnames{author}%
      \setunit{\addcomma\space}%
      \usebibmacro{bbx:savehash}}%
    \usebibmacro{authorstrg}}
  {\global\undef\bbx@lasthash}}

\newbibmacro*{bbx:dashcheck}[2]{%
  \ifboolexpr{
    test {\iffieldequals{fullhash}{\bbx@lasthash}}
    and
    not test \iffirstonpage
  }
  {#1}
  {#2}}
```

Possibly related: [biblatex ignores own lbx file](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/28014/biblatex-ignores-own-lbx-file) and [Using own .lbx file with biblatex](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/569814/using-own-lbx-file-with-biblatex).

Comment: Mystery solved: In `~/Library/texmf/web2c` I had an old .fmt for the book-length document that I had fashioned out of its preamble. As soon as I trashed that  .fmt, the document compiled normally. I remembered that now-obsolete format only after using the `\NewBibliographyString` fix from https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/583988/13492 but got a weird error about a mismatch of character width.

Answer (score 4):

The Basque localisation was added to `biblatex` [about three months ago (2020-11-10)](https://github.com/plk/biblatex/commit/06abea804913a1dd7f200327d4a6124fe6eaf999) and is included in v3.16 of `biblatex` (released 2020-12-31).

If your `mylanguagestrings.lbx` is based on an `.lbx` file from `biblatex` v3.16 or was grabbed from GitHub after 2020-11-10, it might include reference to `langbasque`.

The `.log` shows that the rest of your `biblatex` installation is still at v3.15a (2020-08-23) from before Basque support was added.

**Update your `biblatex` installation and make sure that your custom `.lbx` file is in sync with your `biblatex` version.**

If you need quick workaround and cannot update, you could try adding

```
\NewBibliographyString{langbasque}
\NewBibliographyString{frombasque}
```

to your preamble to avoid the error.

Comment: What in `mylanguagestrings.lbx` would need changing to be in sync? And why isn't biblatex otherwise updated automatically when I run the TeXLive Utility?

Comment: I"m confused here: `kpsewhich biblatex.sty` leads me to the file version 3.16 dated 2020/12/31, yet in the log (from a file listing) I see: `biblatex.sty    2020/08/23 v3.15a programmable bibliographies (PK/MW)`.

Comment: @murray Oh, I thought the `mylanguagestrings.lbx` you posted was just an abbreviated version of the real file. The file you posted looks fine. But the version mismatch you mention in your last comment looks bad. Uninstall `biblatex` and then reinstall it with `tlmgr` (not sure if `tlmgr` will let you do a simple uninstall due to dependencies, if not try `tlmgr install --reinstall biblatex`). If that still does not help, share the full `.log` file. You may have an outdated `biblatex.sty` somewhere that is accidentally picked up.

Comment: I used the Mac TeXLive Utility to reinstall `biblatex`. Still same error. I"ve updated my question to show this.

Comment: @murray Then please share the complete `.log` file of the failing LaTeX run with us. There must be some file somewhere in the wrong version that is picked up instead of the correct v3.16 file

Answer (score 1):

The error was cased by an old .fmt file in ~/Library/texmf/web2c that I had fashioned out of the document's preamble. That format used older versions of packages, including `biblatex` and `babel`.

As soon as I trashed that .fmt, the document compiled normally.

I remembered that now-obsolete format only after using the `\NewBibliographyString` fix from https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/583988/13492. Doing that eliminated the error with `langbasque`, but it caused a new error about a mismatch of character width. And that's what got me thinking!